# No "save" option in Android new contact activity?

Tags: usability, android, save

When I want to add a new contact on stock Android 5.1, I'm presented with this activity:

[image]

What I've never understood about this is **why isn't there a "save" option/button?** Instead, when you tap the back arrow, a message informs you that the contacts is actually saved.

Most of the times, when I see no save option, I assume it would save the content automatically (like Google Docs, ...) which is not the case here.

I'm fairly new to UI/UX design and was wondering:

What reason could be behind it? Is it considered a good practice? Have you seen any similar pattern (on mobile or web)?

Comment: This has been bothering me too for ages. It's really unintuitive UX. It was improved in 6.0 but imo it's still not very good, I'm missing a really affirmative action to lead the user towards completing the action.

Answer (score 3):

That's strange, what version do you have? I have a tick in the top right which saves the contact for me.

[image]

Comment: Strange indeed. I'm on stock 5.1 (Nexus 4) and as far as I remember, it was this way on 5.0, too. Yours is different, is it Marshmallow?

Comment: Yes stock Marshmallow Nexus 6. So maybe they have realised the issue and fixed it. How are you meant to save then in that version? I only joined Android when Marshmallow came out, so not too familiar with older versions

Comment: Yes, it seems someone at Google has asked the same question! On Lollipop, You have to tap the back arrow! It then shows a toast that the contact is saved.

Comment: @Mahm00d Just curious because I don't use an Android phone, but if you only get the back arrow how would you distinguish between saving and cancelling?

Comment: @MichaelLai As far as I know, there is no cancelling. If you don't put anything in the fields and press back, it says empty contact can't be saved (obviously!) and nothing happens. But if there's value in the fields, it would save the contact anyways (even on phone's back button)...

Comment: @Mahm00d That would be a bit annoying if you started filling some details and decided to cancel it, then find that you have to go back to your contact list and delete it.